# React useEffect inside parent component doesnt rerender by changes inside child

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, components, jsx

I have an `App` component that returns only a React component called `Home`. Inside the `App` component I have a `useEffect` that has no dependancy, which I expect to re-render when something changes in the `Home` component, but this doesn't happen. Doesn't React support such a thing?

Comment: Please share a reproducible, minimal code

Comment: You may want to re-read the effect hook documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported out of the box. The child will rerender when parent rerenders but not the other way around.

If every parent rerenders when a child rerender, then even a tiny button state change will cause the whole tree to rerender.

You have callbacks that can help you get around this. The child should be passed a callback function as a prop. Inside this callback function body the parent state will be updated. So now when this function runs (from within the child). The parent also rerenders.

Comment: Finally understood it. Thanks for your explanation